# React.js test fails on finding components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, chai

I have an app build on React, Redux and React-router. I'm writing test using React TestUtils and I found that from the tests you can see below. 
The first expect works: `expect(nav).to.have.length(1);` 
but the second one `expect(modal).to.have.length(1);`

fails with:

> AssertionError: expected [] to have a length of 1 but got 0

App.js:

```js
import React, { Component, cloneElement, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ContactsList from './contactsList';
import Nav from './nav';
import Modal from './modal';
import Header from './header';
import HomeIndex from './homeIndex';
import ErrorBox from './errorBox';
import ImmutablePropTypes from 'react-immutable-proptypes';

export default class App extends Component {
 render = () => {
  const { actions, contacts, router } = this.props;
  return (
   <div>
    <Nav />
    <div className="container">
     <ErrorBox error={contacts.getIn(['error', 'errorMessage'])} show={contacts.getIn(['error', 'showError'])} />
     <Header />
     <div className="contacts-list-container">
      <ContactsList contacts={contacts} />
      <Modal open={contacts.get('showSpinner')} />
      { cloneElement(this.props.children || <HomeIndex/>, { contacts: contacts ,
        addContact: actions.addContactReq, 
        getContact: actions.getContact, 
        contact: contacts.get('contact'), 
        router: router,
        deleteContact: actions.deleteContact,
        editContact: actions.editContact }) }
     </div>
    </div>    
   </div>
  );
 }
}

App.propTypes = {
 actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
 contacts: ImmutablePropTypes.map.isRequired,
 router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

App-spec.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { renderIntoDocument, scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag } from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import App from '../components/app';
import { Map } from 'immutable';

describe('app', () => {

 it('renders properly', () => {
  const component = renderIntoDocument(
   <App  actions={{}} router={{}} contacts={ Map({
    showSpinner: false,
    error: Map({
     showError: false,
     errorMessage: ''
    }),
    contacts: Map(),
    contact: Map()
    }) } />
  );

  const nav = scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(component, 'Nav');
  const modal = scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(component, 'Modal');
  expect(nav).to.have.length(1);
  expect(modal).to.have.length(1);      
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag` looks for actual HTML elements in the component DOM. You want to use `scryRenderedComponentsWithType` to find rendered React components:

```
const modal = scryRenderedComponentsWithType(component, Modal);
```

See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#scryrenderedcomponentswithtype

Your `Nav` call probably works because you have a `<nav>` HTML element in your `Nav` React component.

Comment: Ok, you are right. The second problem is that it is not working with the new stateless components introduced in react v0.14.

Answer (score 0):

scrying needs a component reference iirc. So:

```
import Modal from './components/modal';

// Then later:
const modal = scryRenderedComponentsWithType(component, Modal);
```

This will look for instances of the actual component.